# Disable form submission if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to use function `checkbox()` to disable form submission.

Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code snippet for the JS:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function checkbox() {
        if(document.form.checkbox.checked)
        {
            document.form.submit.disabled=false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.form.submit.disabled=true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the HTML code.

```
<form name="form" action="shop_paypal.php" method="post">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
    <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="UK" />
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"value="YOUTUBE"/>
    <select name="amount" id="amount" style="width:256px; height:32px;">
        <option value="18" id="1">10,000 PINS - $18 </option>
        <option value="35" id="2">20,000 PINS - $35</option>
        <option value="75" id="3">30,000 PINS - $75</option>
        <option value="140" id="4">50,000 PINS - $140</option>
    </select>
    <label>Your Facebook fan page URL: </label><br />
    <input class="input-box" type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"/> 
    <label class="agree">I agree to <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></label>
    <input type="image" src="images/products/buynow.gif" class="submit" onclick= "checkbox();" name = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and notice how the function is simplyfied and calling is moved to the checkbox itself. When it's checked, button is enabled, and when unchecked, it's disabled (this is also a default state).

Here's also a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kL7We/

```
<script>
    function enableSending() {
        document.form.submit.disabled = !document.form.checkbox.checked;
    }
</script>

<form name="form" action="shop_paypal.php" method="post">
   <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
   <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
   <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="UK" />
   <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
   <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"value="YOUTUBE"/>
 <select name="amount" id="amount" style="width:256px; height:32px;">
       <option value="18" id="1">10,000 PINS - $18 </option>
       <option value="35" id="2">20,000 PINS - $35</option>
       <option value="75" id="3">30,000 PINS - $75</option>
       <option value="140" id="4">50,000 PINS - $140</option>
  </select>
  <label>Your Facebook fan page URL: </label><br />
      <input class="input-box" type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick= "enableSending();"/> 
    <label for="checkbox" class="agree">I agree to</label> <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
    <input type="button" src="images/products/buynow.gif" class="submit"  name = "submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: @nikica.. that worked fine too..
can you suggest why my code wasn't working?

Comment: You used "checkbox" as your function name - which is also an object name so there was this error in JS... "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function". But there are also two logical flaws - you executed the function on the submit button itself - and since it needed to be active, the disabling it (after it's already clicked) didn't make any sense. Upon that, the IF statement you wrote is actually setting the button to disabled state when it IS checked - opposite from what you tried to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious first thought would be:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
function check (){
    return document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', check);
```